# Programmatically, I want a Drupal 7 content type with no "body" field

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, field, content-type

In Drupal 7, I have programmatically created a new content type with 2 new fields.   Going to fill in the new content type, it displays a "Body" field that I do not want filled.  Is there a way to programmatically install the new content type to hide the body field.   I know I can use CSS to hide the body field, but, I think that is probably a kludge.  I would like to use the correct programmatic method to hide the Body field.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using [`field_delete_instance()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_delete_instance/7)

*Let us know if you need further assistance.*

Answer (score 2):

Content types do not have the body field by default - it is usually added when creating the content type:

```
// add content types
$ctypes = _my_module_get_content_types();          // get content types
foreach($ctypes as $ctype => $data){
  if (!in_array($ctype, node_type_get_names())) {  // check for collisions
    $data = node_type_set_defaults($data);         // default *does not* add body field
    node_type_save($data);
    node_add_body_field($data);                    // add body here (typical usage)
  }
}
```

look around for the `node_add_body_field()` fn and remove it if present.